# Ubuntu 12.10 : is possible to use dash as a Google desktop alternative?

Tags: 12.10, unity-dash, google

I just need to know what asked in question subject.

May I use dash to index & search documents, emails, pdfs in a way similar to Google Desktop does?

Is also possible to specify which directories to search either directly or indirectly, for example creating softlinks in my user homedir to my documents folder ?

Comment: you can do this in gnome shell

Answer (score 4):

With a special lens, this is possible. You can use the Recoll lens to search your files (with an index) just like you do with Google Desktop.

You can install it from this PPA: ppa:recoll-backports/recoll-1.15-on

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:recoll-backports/recoll-1.15-on
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install recoll-lens
```